# facebook internationalization deprecated tags

Tags: facebook, internationalization

I am trying to develop a multi-language app for facebook.

I saw the reference documents regarding internationalization, but they use fbml which is being deprecated!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Here is the tag info, which clearly states that it's not going to work in a few months:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/intl/

So how am I supposed to proceed?